# Is ArcObjects SDK for .NET available with ArcGIS for Home Use or free trial license?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-license-manager, basic-license-level, arcgis-personal-use

I currently have a 6 month free trial of ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 that I got online with an authorization number from an Esri Press book and I've read that ArcObjects is bundled with the Desktop license but I don't know if it applies to what I have. I'm not sure that I have the proper installation media with a free trial.

Would the only other way be to gain Customer Service access rights through a Global Account?

Answer (score 2):

You do not say where you "read that ArcObjects is bundled with the Desktop license" but with respect to your question about the [ArcGIS for Home Use Program](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home):

This annual subscription gets you:

- ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced (ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro)
- The most popular ArcGIS for Desktop extensions
- ArcGIS for Desktop software updates
- ArcGIS Online Named User Account
- 100 service credits for data storage, premium data access, and geocoding and analysis
- A suite of ready-to-use apps for use anywhere, on any device
- A Living Atlas of the World with maps and data, including access to foundation content from Esri, on thousands of topics
- Installation support

There is no mention of the ArcObjects SDK for .NET being included, and from [Downloading ArcObjects SDKs for .NET?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85993/downloading-arcobjects-sdks-for-net) I would not expect it to be:

> the ArcObjects SDK (.NET or Java) ... is a licensed product

Consequently, I think you should contact Esri to be certain of your options.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted ESRI UK about developing with ArcObjects on the Home Use licence, and they stated that they do not allow it and that an EDN licence should be purchased for development purposes. The Home Use downloads also do not include the .NET SDK, reinforcing this statement. ESRI themselves, of course, may have a different view, so it's still worth contacting them. And you might be able to convince them that a Home Developer licence would be useful!