# ArcObjects SDK for .NET Framework with Annual Educational Advanced (ArcInfo) Single Use License

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, visual-studio, arcgis-license-manager, advanced-license-level

I usually use my organization's ESRI account when at work, but I am now working at my home Desktop PC.  On my home PC, I have an ArcGIS 10.6 annual educational license that I do not want to sacrifice.  It is an Advanced (ArcInfo) Single Use license.  I also have an ESRI Developer subscription through my organization, so I am able to download the ArcObjects SDK for .NET Framework to my home PC.  I also have Visual Studio 2017 Professional on my home PC, which I downloaded BEFORE downloading the ArcObjects SDK for .NET Framework.  When I downloaded the SDK, I ensured that I downloaded the bit for Visual Studio 2017 Professional.  The immediate problem is that Visual Studio is not aware of my ArcObjects SDK.  When I attempt to add a new project, the ArcGIS menu is not on the left side of the New Project dialog box.

Is anybody able to provide a solution, help me troubleshoot or confirm that the SDK will not work with my educational license or maybe it is my Advanced Single Use license that the SDK does not like?

I have read this:  [Is the ArcObjects SDK for .NET available with an ArcGIS for Home Use or free trial license?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181819/is-the-arcobjects-sdk-for-net-available-with-an-arcgis-for-home-use-or-free-tri)

Comment: In what order did you *install* the software? It should be 1) Visual Studio 2) ArcGIS Desktop 3) ArcGIS SDK

Comment: @Berend That could be it.  I installed ArcGIS Desktop first, then Visual Studio, then the SDK.  I can't reinstall ArcGIS Desktop, because that would sacrifice my educational license.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install visual studio 2013 and visual studio 2015 to get this to work? The way I develop is I will install 2013 and then install 2015 and then install the arc objects SDK. I write my tools targeted for 10.4.1 and they work all the way up to 10.8. See if that works :)

Comment: Thanks @Chris Stayte.  I'll give that a shot if uninstalling and reinstalling 2017, 2019 and the SDK does not work.

Comment: @Chris ArcObjects 10.6 supports both Visual Studio 2015 and 2017. Installing 2013 shouldn't be necessary. 2015 *may* help, but 2017 should work too. It does for me.